# Observable.Do never fires, even when the underlying IObservable changes

Tags: c#, wpf, system.reactive, reactiveui

I'm getting a bit of a crash course in ReactiveUI and `System.Reactive.Linq` after finding that a UI library I need uses it for everything.  It seems to be pretty understandable for the most part, but there's one operation that isn't doing anything.

I have a control whose value I need to use in two places.  I have an `IObservable<T>` representing its value, which I'm using as follows:

case 1:  I need to feed a value to another observable, by combining this with another observable value.  So I produce it using
`Observable.CombineLatest(myObservable, otherObservable, (m, o) => ProduceValue(m, o))` This updates exactly as expected.  From this, I know that `myObservable` is firing updates correctly.

case 2:
I need to use this value elsewhere, in a non-observable context.  So: `myObservable.Do(v => UpdateViewModelWith(v))`.  **This never fires.**  I've verified that by putting a breakpoint in the lambda and running it under the debugger.

From case 1 I know that the observable is firing correctly.  As I understand it, observables are conceptually a lot like Events, (with a bunch of machinery to make them feel more like `IEnumerable`s,) and like Events are perfectly capable of accepting multiple listeners, so the fact that there's two of them shouldn't be a problem.  (Verified by changing the order in which the two listeners are set up, which produces no change in observed behavior.)  So what can cause case 2 to never run?

Comment: Observables need a subscription. Try replacing Do with Subscribe. Does that work?

Comment: @Shlomo That worked, thanks!  If you can make that into an answer explaining why `Subscribe` works when `Do` doesn't, I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Erwin's answer is close. Just to elaborate:

`Do`, like most Rx-related functions, is an *operator*. Operators do nothing without subscriptions. For example:

```
var source = Observable.Range(0, 5);
var squares = source.Select(i => i * i);
var logged = squares.Do(i => Console.WriteLine($"Logged Do: {i}));

var sameThingChained = Observable.Range(0, 5)
    .Select(i => i * i)
    .Do(i => Console.WriteLine($"Chained Do: {i}));

//until here, we're in no-op land.
```

`Range`, `Select` and `Do` are all operators, which do nothing without a subscription. If you want any of this to do anything, you need a subscription.

```
var subscription = logged.Subscribe(i => Console.Writeline($"Subscribe: {i}");
```

Output:

```
Logged Do: 0
Subscribe: 0
Logged Do: 1
Subscribe: 1
Logged Do: 4
Subscribe: 4
Logged Do: 9
Subscribe: 9
Logged Do: 16
Subscribe: 16
```

Generally, side-effect code (non-functional code) should reside in a `Subscribe` function. `Do` is best used for logging/debugging. So if I wanted to log the original, non-square integer, I could do as follows.

```
var chainedSub = Observable.Range(0, 5)
    .Do(i => Console.WriteLine($"Original int: {i}"));
    .Select(i => i * i)
    .Subscribe(i => Console.Writeline($"Subscribe: {i}");
```

In pure Rx.NET (without ReactiveUI), there's only one way to get a subscription: the various `Subscribe` overloads. However, ReactiveUI does have a bunch of functions that create subscriptions themselves so you don't have to deal with them (like `ToProperty`). If you're using ReactiveUI, those are probably a better choice than `Subscribe`.

Answer (score 4):

I would guess that you are using an observable without any subscribers, which means it never fires and `Do` is never activated.

The function that you want is likely [`IObservable<T>.Subscribe<T>(Action<T> action)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/ff402849(v=vs.103)):

`myObservable.Subscribe(v => UpdateViewModelWith(v))`

The difference between `Do` and `Subscribe` is that `Do` is a side effect. It's something that happens on the side of the pipeline: *"pass me some values, oh and, by the way, do this on the side."* But if there is no pipeline, the values are never sent.

On the other hand `Subscribe` registers an observer. It actually creates a pipeline, by telling the observable: *"hey someone is watching, send stuff!"*

To better understand what it means, you can also look at the return types:

- `Do` returns an `IObservable<T>`, since the observable is not consumed.
- `Subscribe` returns an `IDisposable`, since it registers an observer.

**Important:** make sure to include `using System`, otherwise you will only see `IObservable<T>.Subscribe<T>(IObserver<T> observer)`.

By the way, I also got confused regarding Do and Subscribe just this morning and received help on the very nice [Reactive Slack](https://www.reactiveui.net/slack/). I highly recommend joining if you're working with Rx or ReactiveUI!

Comment: "a cold observable without any subscribers" - It makes no difference if the observable is hot or cold; the only part that matters is the lack of a subscription. Your statement is misleading.

Comment: You're right! I had a misunderstanding around hot / cold observables, thanks for clearing it up. I edited my answer to make sure it doesn't mislead anyone.